# Kafka-connect to PostgreSQL - org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize topic to Avro

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

### Setup

I've installed latest (7.0.1) version of Confluent platform in standalone mode on Ubuntu virtual machine.

### Python producer for Avro format

Using [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro_producer.py) sample Avro producer to generate stream from data to Kafka topic (pmu214).

Producer seems to work ok. I'll give full code on request.
Producer output:

```
Raw data: {"pmu_id": 2, "time": 1644577001.22, "measurements": [{"stream_id": 2, "stat": "ok", "phasors": [[27.22379, 0.0], [24.672079638784002, -2.075237618663568], [25.11940552135938, 2.10660756475536], [3248.794237867336, -0.06468446412011757], [3068.6629010042793, -2.152472189017548], [2990.0809353594427, 2.031751749658583], [0.0, 0.0], [3101.9477751890026, -0.06193618455080409]], "analog": [], "digital": [0], "frequency": 50.022, "rocof": 0}]}
PMU record b'e5c1e5a8-3e44-465d-98c4-93f896ec1b14' successfully produced to pmu214 [0] at offset 38256
```

### KSQL

In `ksqld` it seems that record reached `ksqldb` ok:

```
rowtime: 2022/02/11 09:48:05.431 Z, key: [26151234-d3dd-4b7c-9222-2867@3486128305426751843/-], value: \x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x04\xAA\xC3\xB1\xA0\x0C\x04\x04ok\xC2p\xD9A\x0F`\x
9F>.b\xC6A\xB9\xC8\xE2\xBF\xC5%\xC8A\x13v\x1A@\x8FVKE\xF9\xF8u>\xC5\xC5?E\xEA\xBA\xEC\xBF\xE0\xFA:E\xD5~\x15@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x84\x07BEs\xD1w>\x04[]\x020b\x0
2, partition: 0
Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
Topic printing ceased
```

### Kafka-connect

Here is command used to connect to PostgreSQL:

```
bin/connect-standalone etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties
```

Here is content of `connect-avro-standalone.properties`:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
name=sinkIRIpostgre
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
topics=pmu214

connection.user=mydbuser
connection.password=mypass
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
insert.mode=insert
pk.mode=record_key
pk.fields=MESSAGE_KEY

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

I didn't change anything in `connect-standalone.properties` except plugins I've installed.

```
plugin.path=/home/proton/kafkaConnectors/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.3.2,/home/proton/kafkaConverters/confluentinc-kafka-connect-json-schema-converter-7.0.1,/home/proton/kafkaConverters/confluentinc-kafka-connect-avro-converter-7.0.1/
```

### ERROR received

> ERROR [sinkIRIpostgre|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=sinkIRIpostgre-0}
> Error converting message key in topic 'pmu214' partition 0 at offset 0
> and timestamp 1644560570372: Failed to deserialize data for topic
> pmu214 to Avro:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:552)
> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize
> data for topic pmu214 to Avro:    at
> io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertKey(WorkerSinkTask.java:550)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$3(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:332)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally ran the Python sample code, then the key is not Avro, so a failure on the `key.converter` would be expected, as shown

> Error converting message key

Comment: Sample code is adapted to my solution. It seem to work. It's not clear to me what should I than put under key.converter?

Comment: StringConverter would be a start, since the producer is using string keys, not Avro, but I don't know what you've changed in the Python code.